# Given six 3D vectors a,b,c,d,e,f, find the rotation matrix R such that Ra, Rb, Rc are respectively perp. to d,e,f (assuming there exists a solution)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, analytic-geometry, rotations

(EDIT: I also welcome a solution to the special case where d, e, f are coplanar)

I think this problem can be solved iteratively, but I was wondering if there could be a closed-form solution...

Anyone with an idea for a closed-form method?

Comment: Note that the rotations preserve angles. So the request might not have solution. For example $d,e,f$ form an orthonormal system, and $a,b,c$ are collinear, no matter what $R$ you choose, you cannot make more than one vector perpendicular to $d,e,f$. You need to have more constraints on your problem.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for your comment. I updated the question.

Comment: Seem to be the Orthogonal Procrustes problen https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem

Answer (score 0):

Different idea. For any linearly independent $a$ and $d$, by Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization the vector $a'$ is orthogonal to $d$:

$$a' = a - \frac{(d \cdot a)}{(d \cdot d)} d$$

So now we are looking for $R$ such that:

$$\min_R \sum_i {\|R a_i - a'_i\|^2}$$
$$s.t. \ \ \ R^T R = I$$

Which is an instance of the Wahba's Problem:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem

which solution would be straightforward to compute using SVD. Of course the Gram-Schmidt introduces a change in the scale of vectors, that could be compensated by normalization. Also, Wahba's problem admit weights $w_i$ in order to give more importance to some pair or vectors than others, if needed.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work either. I think it's because the angle between a & d is not necessarily the same as the angle between b & e, and so forth...

Comment: Rotations preserve angles. If the angle is not the same then there is no solution. Although this method is given the best least squares approximation to a silution. Also recall that in my answer you can use weights to influence scale incariance and relative  inportance. Also, the orientation of the new frame $a'$, $b'$ and $c'$ should be consistent with $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: This is not true. Sure, the angles between (a,b,c) are the same as the angles between (d,e,f), but it doesn't mean that the angle between (a,d) is the same as (b,e). Imagine a 2D kite. One pair of opposite angles are the same (so the angle is preserved between them), but the other angles are not the same.

Comment: @SeongHunLee Sorry, that is right. I see why my solution doesn't work. I have the wrong picture on my mind. I need to draw some pictures with pen and paper.